# Issue with uploading images in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

In my app,I am uploading some pictures inside the public/images folder. Everything used to be working fine,but not anymore. I get a success message,meaning that the image has been uploaded in the folder,however,I can't see it:(. And this is what postman gives me back.(POST = *http://localhost:3000/image*).

```
    {
     "success": true,
     "message": "Image uploaded!"
    }
```

That's a bit strange. Everything seems correct. Here is my code.

**imageRouter**

```
        var express = require('express');
        var imageRouter = express.Router();
        var multer = require('multer');

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, './public/images')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.jpg')
            }
        });

        var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('myImage');



        imageRouter.post('/', function (req, res) {
            upload(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    // An error occurred when uploading
                }
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Image uploaded!'
                });

                // Everything went fine
            })
        });


        module.exports = imageRouter;
```

And **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
            var path = require('path');
            var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
            var logger = require('morgan');
            var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            var mongoose = require('mongoose');
            var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/larissaApp';

            mongoose.connect(url);
            var db = mongoose.connection;
            db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error:'));
            db.once('open',function(){
               console.log("Connected correctly to server"); 
            });

            var routes = require('./routes/index');
            var users = require('./routes/users');
            var newsRouter = require('./routes/newsRouter');
            var cityRouter = require('./routes/cityRouter');
            var imageRouter = require('./routes/imageRouter');
            var mayorRouter = require('./routes/mayorRouter');
            var deputyMayorRouter = require('./routes/deputyMayorRouter');
            var app = express();
            // view engine setup
            app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
            app.set('view engine', 'jade');
            // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
            //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
            app.use(logger('dev'));

            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
            app.use(cookieParser());
            app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

            app.use('/', routes);
            app.use('/users', users);
            app.use('/news',newsRouter);
            app.use('/news',newsRouter);
            app.use('/city',cityRouter);
            app.use('/image',imageRouter);
            app.use('/mayor',mayorRouter);
            app.use('/deputymayor',deputyMayorRouter);
            // catch 404 and forward to error handler
            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
              var err = new Error('Not Found');
              err.status = 404;
              next(err);
            });
            // error handlers
            // development error handler
            // will print stacktrace
            if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
              app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
                res.status(err.status || 500);
                res.render('error', {
                  message: err.message,
                  error: err
                });
              });
            }
            // production error handler
            // no stacktraces leaked to user
            app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
              res.status(err.status || 500);
              res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: {}
              });
            });
            module.exports = app;
```

The server listening part is inside my **bin/www** file.

And finally I am using *expreess-4.15.2*.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1):

You're always responding with success regardless of the outcome since you're not using a `return` to stop execution within the `POST /image` route handler. Just return a response when an error occurs and you'll stop getting the success response for every outcome.

```
imageRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
        if (err) {
            // An error occurred when uploading
            return res.sendStatus(500)
        }

        // Everything went fine
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Image uploaded!'
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: I added your code,but I still have the same problem even if I get a success message!

Comment: @Theo try changing your storage destination to `../public/images`, your `public` dir is inside your project root, your `imageRouter` is inside `/routers/` which is one level down in your folders.

Comment: Still nothing:(